# Run elixir code inside gulpfile whenever code in a .scss file is changed

Tags: javascript, laravel, sass, gulp

I'm trying to run gulp whenever content in the app.scss file is changed.

Below is the code that I'm trying but its not working.

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

 gulp.task('watch', function(){
     gulp.watch('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', ['default']);
 });

 elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Watching Assets For Changes

Since it is inconvenient to run the gulp command on your terminal after every change to your assets, you may use the gulp watch command. This command will continue running in your terminal and watch your assets for any changes. When changes occur, new files will automatically be compiled:

**gulp watch**

Comment: would running this command have any negative effect on the performance of laptop, due to it constantly looking for updates?